# In square api, how do I access a location's opening hours?

Tags: square-connect

I am trying to access a location's opening hours via the Square API?
These are editable via the square account dashboard (under settings>locations), but I can't see what endpoint to access them.

When I try

GET /v2/locations

a get a list of locations, but no opening hours fields.
Is there some other endpoint I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Not all information that is accessible in the dashboard is available via API. You cannot retrieve company hours via API at this time.